# Java - Add/Remove JPanel classes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to make the JPanels swap from one to another. Sounds simple, but I'm struggling due to having my panels all in different classes.

I have 4 classes:
 - GUI (Main class)
 - BankingAppMainFrame (JFrame class)
 - BankingAppStartPanel (JPanel class) <- I want to remove this JPanel
 - BankingAppLoginPanel (JPanel class) <- I want to add this JPanel

Here is my relevant JFrame code:

```
//This is the only way i didn't get errors xD
public void panelSwap(JFrame z, JPanel x, JPanel y) {
    z.remove(x);
    z.add(y);
}
```

Here is my relevant BankingAppStartPanel code:

```
LoginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        //I thought I'd need to instance all my classes

        BankingAppMainFrame mainFrame = new BankingAppMainFrame();
        BankingAppStartPanel startPanel = new BankingAppStartPanel();
        BankingAppLoginPanel loginPanel = new BankingAppLoginPanel();

        //This is calling the panelSwap method from the main Class

        mainFrame.panelSwap(mainFrame, startPanel, loginPanel);
    }
});
```

The BankingAppLoginPanel is just a blank panel at the moment until I can get this to work.

What I'm trying to do is remove the current Panel (In this case "BankingAppStartPanel" and replace it with the "BankingAppLoginPanel".

Comment: Don't you have any idea to reconsider your approach? Why you want to do something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//This is the only way i didn't get errors xD
public void panelSwap(JFrame z, JPanel x, JPanel y) {
    z.remove(x);
    z.add(y);
}
```

- [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) hasn't any notifier implemented in API(s) that notify about changes in visible Swing GUI, you have to notify programatically by calling `z.revalidate()` and `z.repaint()`
- there is shortcuts by calling `JFrame.pack()` in the cases when you need to change [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)s bounds too

---

- use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), with `JFrame.pack()` in the cases when you need to change `JFrame`s bounds

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll try using CardLayout

Answer (score 3):

If you planning to go ahead with this "swapping" panels approach, you better try using [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Cheers! I'll check it out.